# Why did my Action Cable (Rails) messages stop being received on 1 client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

I've had Action Cable feeding information to signed-in users in my application for many moons, but recently my main development computer has had a problem.

In all my environments, Production and Staging, the Action Cable functionality feeds the info correctly to other computers like my phone, backup computer, and my buddy's computer, but my computer doesn't get anything.

The server logs look fine, they send the Action Cable messages, but my computer doesn't receive them.  I'd give you more information but I have no idea what would help for this. I restarted my computer and turning my local server off, still nothing. The local environment works fine though.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]", especially the information about what is on topic. Your question tells us very little useful information so I'd recommend adding a lot more diagnostic information, or possibly checking [su] to see if it's a better fit for your question.

Comment: Thanks! Its been a good 5 years so far!  I will make the title better you're right its not quite up to specs!